# How to prove identities of a boolean equation?

Tags: digital-logic

I have a equation which I'm trying to solve but stuck at a point.

$$(a + b).(\bar{a}.\bar{c} + c).(\overline{\bar{b} + ac}) = \bar{a}.b$$

This is what I've tried so far,

$$(a + b).((\bar{a} + c).(c + \bar{c})).(\overline{(\bar{b} + a). (\bar{b} + c)})$$ $$-->c + \bar{c} = 1$$
$$(a + b).(\bar{a} + c).(\overline{(\bar{b}.\bar{b})+(\bar{b}+c)+(a.\bar{b})+a.c})$$

I feel like there's a mistake here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually drawing a truth table for both sides of the equation and showing they are identical is considered a proof.

Comment: @EugeneSh So I just have to draw two truth tables for both equation and if they are equal then it proves the identities. Will that be enough? I was assuming I need to manually solve the equation.

Comment: Depends on what you are *expected* to do, as I guess it is some exercise?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Then you should know the topic and understand what the requirements are. If it is application of Boolean algebra, then you probably go with your original approach. But if it is K-maps or truth tables, a corresponding approach should be taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks unnecessarily complicated.

The first point of simplification will be on the most complex term which is \$(\overline{\bar{b} + ac})\$ . Apply [de-morgan's law](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mathematics-properties-boolean-algebra/) there and reach the shortest expression (You may have to apply it twice).

Then all you have to do is to simply follow the [distributive law](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mathematics-properties-boolean-algebra/) on the three terms left with, and single out the common terms. You should be reaching the answer in a minute.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101062/discussion-on-answer-by-mitu-raj-how-to-prove-identities-of-a-boolean-equation). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).